# Where to place pretrained machine learning models in python package for easy access

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask

I have been writing a personal python package for machine learning purposes. Some of the modules in the package utilize a pretrained model. I am having issues accessing this pretrained model when trying to use the package in a flask app. The directory I'm working in is organized in the following way:

```
-- root
  -- flaskapp          #folder for my flask app
    -- app
      -- templates
        -- index.html
      -- __init__.py
      -- routes.py
    -- flaskapp.py
  -- pipeline          #folder for my python package 
    -- __init__.py
    -- sentiment
      -- __init__.py
      -- logistic.py
  -- models            #folder for my pretrained models
    -- pretrained_model.joblib
```

Here, the sentiment folder contains the python file that loads the serialized model. To use it in `routes.py` of my flask app, I would do:

```py
from pipeline.sentiment.logistic import sentiment_model
```

where `sentiment_model.py` then contains the following lines:

```py
import joblib
model = joblib.load('models/pretrained_model.joblib')
```

Currently, in order to use my `pipeline` package in the flask app, I am attempting to append the package to my path in the `routes.py` file of my flask app. When using the package in other python files, I can only access the models folder if it is in the `root` directory that I am working in, as laid out in the structure of my folders above. If I place the `models` folder inside of the `sentiment` folder, I get the following error:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/pretrained_model.joblib'
```

I'm assuming I'm getting this error because my `models` folder is not in the root directory, but this seems wrong since ideally I'd want to be able to bundle the package with the pretrained model. Where can I place the `models` folder in the package, and what changes would I have to make to the structure of my package, so that I can access the models folder when importing the package in another file? Would I have to do something like put an`__init__.py` file inside of my `models` folder?

Comment: always place them alongside your python file that runs the model in the same directory, otherwise if you store them in a different folder of the same directory, you are getting an error because the models folder is not inside your  logistic folder from where you are calling it.. that's the mess

Comment: Thanks for your help. I placed the `models` folder into the logistic folder. Then, to access it from my flask directory, I used sys to append the root directory to my path. I am still getting a file not found error when attempting to use this model in my routes.py though.